# Troubles with compiling .py file to .app using py2app

Tags: python, python-3.x, compiler-errors, compilation, py2app

I want to make an app file with py2app. I installed py2app with pip, and proceeded to create the app file in terminal:

```
$ cd /Users/<username>/Desktop/pytoapp
$ py2applet --make-setup a_py2app.py
Wrote setup.py
```

Up until this point it went all right, but watch what happened next (skip to the 3 last rows for the relevant information):

```
$ python setup.py py2app
running py2app
creating /Users/<username>/Desktop/pytoapp/build
creating /Users/<username>/Desktop/pytoapp/build/bdist.macosx-10.14-intel
creating /Users/<username>/Desktop/pytoapp/build/bdist.macosx-10.14-intel/python2.7-standalone
creating /Users/<username>/Desktop/pytoapp/build/bdist.macosx-10.14-intel/python2.7-standalone/app
creating /Users/<username>/Desktop/pytoapp/build/bdist.macosx-10.14-intel/python2.7-standalone/app/collect
creating /Users/<username>/Desktop/pytoapp/build/bdist.macosx-10.14-intel/python2.7-standalone/app/temp
creating /Users/<username>/Desktop/pytoapp/dist
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.14-intel/python2.7-standalone/app/lib-dynload
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.14-intel/python2.7-standalone/app/Frameworks
*** using recipe: virtualenv ***
*** using recipe: sip ***
*** using recipe: email ***
*** filtering dependencies ***
475 total
69 filtered
9 orphaned
406 remaining
*** create binaries ***
*** byte compile python files ***
byte-compiling /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.py to _markerlib/__init__.pyc

[…]
[reams of unimportant crap]
[…]

bdist.macosx-10.14-intel/python2.7-standalone/app/collect/test/testrgb.uue
copying file /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/test/floating_points.txt -> /Users/<username>/Desktop/pytoapp/build/bdist.macosx-10.14-intel/python2.7-standalone/app/collect/test/floating_points.txt
*** creating application bundle: a_py2app ***
error: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/Users/<username>/Desktop/pytoapp/dist/a_py2app.app/Contents/MacOS/a_py2app'
```

I get an error, saying "operation not permitted". How do I resolve this? I'm the admin, and I use Python 3.7.